# Select where record does not exists

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I am trying out my hands on oracle 11g. I have a requirement such that I want to fetch those id from list which does not exists in table.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM STOCK
where  item_id in ('1','2'); // Return those records where result is null
```

I mean if `item_id '1'` is not present in db then the query should return me `1`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

You need to store the values in some sort of "table".  Then you can use `left join` or `not exists` or something similar:

```
with ids as (
      select 1 as id from dual union all
      select 2 from dual
     )
select ids.id
from ids
where not exists (select 1 from stock s where s.item_id = ids.id);
```

Comment: But if the list is very huge then do i have to do *Union all * for each element.

Comment: @Anandj.Kadhi . . . You need some way to construct the list.  If it is already in the database somehow, then you can just use a query.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` to an in-line table that contains the values to be searched:

```
SELECT t1.val
FROM (
   SELECT '1' val UNION ALL SELECT '2'
) t1
LEFT JOIN STOCK t2 ON t1.val = t2.item_id
WHERE t2.item_id IS NULL
```

Comment: But if the list is very huge then do i have to do *Union all * for each element.

Answer (score 1):

First create the list of possible IDs (e.g. 0 to 99 in below query). You can use a recursive cte for this. Then select these IDs and remove the IDs already present in the table from the result:

```
with possible_ids(id) as
(
  select 0 as id from dual
  union all
  select id + 1 as id from possible_ids where id < 99
)
select id from possible_ids
minus
select item_id from stock;
```

Answer (score 1):

A primary concern of the OP seems to be a terse notation of the query, notably the set of values to test for. The straightforwwrd recommendation would be to retrieve these values by another query or to generate them as a union of queries from the dual table (see the other answers for this).

The following alternative solution allows for a verbatim specification of the test values under the following conditions:

1. There is a character that does not occur in any of the test values provided ( in the example that will be `-` )
2. The number of values to test stays well below 2000 (to be precise, the list of values plus separators must be written as a varchar2 literal, which imposes the length limit ). However, this should not be an actual concern - If the test involves lists of hundreds of ids, these lists should definitely be retrieved froma table/view.

***Caveat***

Whether this method is worth the hassle ( not to mention potential performance impacts ) is questionable, imho.

***Solution***

The test values will be provided as a single varchar2 literal with `-` separating the values which is as terse as the specification as a list argument to the `IN` operator. The string starts and ends with `-`.

```
'-1-2-3-156-489-4654648-'
```

The number of items is computed as follows:

```
select cond, regexp_count ( cond, '[-]' ) - 1 cnt_items  from (select '-1-2-3-156-489-4654648-' cond from dual)
```

A list of integers up  to the number of items starting with 1 can be generated using the `LEVEL` pseudocolumn from hierarchical queries:

```
select level from dual connect by level < 42;
```

The n-th integer from that list will serve to extract the n-th value from the string (exemplified for the 4th value) :

```
select substr ( cond, instr(cond,'-', 1, 4 )+1, instr(cond,'-', 1, 4+1 ) - instr(cond,'-', 1, 4 ) - 1 ) si from (select cond, regexp_count ( cond, '[-]' ) - 1 cnt_items  from (select '-1-2-3-156-489-4654648-' cond from dual) );
```

The non-existent stock ids are generated by subtracting the set of stock ids from the set of values. Putting it all together:

```
    select substr ( cond, instr(cond,'-',1,level )+1, instr(cond,'-',1,level+1 ) - instr(cond,'-',1,level ) - 1 ) si 
      from (
              select cond
                   , regexp_count ( cond, '[-]' ) - 1 cnt_items
                from (
                        select '-1-2-3-156-489-4654648-' cond from dual
                     )
           ) 
connect by level <= cnt_items + 1
     minus
    select item_id from stock
         ;
```